# Parse NameValuePairs to String, then String to NameValuePairs

Tags: java, http-post

I have a `List<NameValuePair>` object where i put random data:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key","value"));
```

I need to store this data into a SQLite database, so I cast the object to a string:

```
nameValuePairs.toString();
```

Of course then I need to get the data again, but I dont know if it is possible. Is there a simple way to get back the `NameValuePair` object from the string?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For one thing, calling toString() on an object is NOT the same as casting it to a string. Can you store the data in 2 columns instead of one? Then rebuilding the NameValuePair object would be simple.

Comment: Have you outputted what the call to `toString()` returns? Perhaps it returns a string similar to `"name=foo:value=bar"` that wouldn't be to hard to parse.

Comment: A database table is about single values in each column. If you try to cram name/value pairs into it, you are violating database normalization (1NF, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). It already is hard to do what you try, but it will get you in a world of hurt later on. Design your database now, before you have to deal with legacy code and data, then store the pairs properly, probably in a new table.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Don't do it. Not worth it. Lots of extra work, you cannot rely on the output format, you maybe cannot even assume that the data does not contain special characters the output format uses as delimeters.

Comment: Thanks, i will consider the normalization warning and avoid parsing to string, its to complicated to get the data again.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i will consider other way to do this job.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop and iterate the data, then you can store it in SQLite

```
 for (NameValuePair nvp : data) 
 {
     String name = nvp.getName();
     String value = nvp.getValue();
 }
```